# Fractions in Python

Tags: python, fractions

Is there anyway to compute a fraction, e.g. 2/3 or 1/2, in Python without importing the `math` module?

The code snippet is simple:

```
# What is the cube root of your number
n = float(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
print(n**(1/3))
```

Extraordinarily simple code, but everywhere I look it's telling me to import the `math` module. I just want to add that snippet into a bigger code I'm working on. I keep getting 1 as my answer because Python feels like 1/3 is 0 rather than .333333333. I could put .33333, but that's just a temporary fix and I want to know how to perform this very basic computation for future projects.

Comment: Is this a Python 2 thing? Works as expected for me w/p3

Comment: @TheUnfunCat: Yes, in Python 3, float division is standard; use `//` for integer division.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `from __future__ import division` to make integer division return floats where necessary (so that 1/3 will result in 0.333333...).

Even without doing that, you can get your fractional value by doing `1.0/3` instead of `1/3`.  (The `1.0` makes the first number a float rather than an integer, which makes division work right.)

Comment: +1 for the 1.0/3 suggestion, and for using `1.0` instead of `1.`

Answer (score 6):

There is a fractions module in the standard library that can perform various tasks on fractions. If you have a lot of computations on fractions, You can do them without converting them to float. http://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html

Answer (score 2):

Simply add a decimal and fraction part to cast the operation to a float:

```
>>> n=float(raw_input('Enter a number: ')); print n**(1.0/3)
Enter a number: 2
1.25992104989
```

Or, use `float` explicitly:

```
>>> n=float(raw_input('Enter a number: ')); print n**(float(1)/3)
Enter a number: 2
1.25992104989
```

Or, use Python 3's style of division:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> n=float(raw_input('Enter a number: ')); print n**(1/3)
Enter a number: 2
1.25992104989
```

Any of those three methods works. I prefer the first.