# How do I take a fraction as an input in Python, and use the fraction's value for arithmetic?

Tags: python

Here's an example code I made to illustrate my problem. If the input is an integer or a decimal, it works as intended. But if the input is a fraction such as 4/5, it throws a ValueError since 4/5 is a string that can not be converted into a float.

```
myinput=input("Enter number. ")
doubleofmyinput=float(myinput)*2
print(doubleofmyinput)
```

This is not an issue when not using `input()` since float(4/5) works whereas float("4/5") doesn't, while both float("4.5") and float(4.5) are valid. Thanks.

Comment: No, `float("4/5")` *DOESN'T* work!  Whatever made you think it might???  Most of the time, folks just use a floating point variable, in decimal or [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).  If you wish - for whatever reason - you could always specify a "fraction" by passing two integer arguments into your function: , e.g. `myfunction(numerator, denominator)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fractions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763757/fractions-in-python)

Comment: @paulsm4 well, `float(4/5)` *does* work, but that's because `4/5` isn't a "fraction", it's an expression that gets evaluated to a float

Comment: So, in general you have to parse your input for whatever you expect. I will note, however, that `fractions.Fraction` will handle your input and work with other python numeric types

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: the OP said `float("4/5")`, which is of course nonsense.  Your suggestion about [fractions.Fraction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) was great!  That's similar to what I was suggesting ... but I wasn't aware there was already an existing Python class for it :)  Cool :)

Comment: @paulsm4 i'm just pointing out that the OP said "since float(4/5) works whereas float("4/5") doesn't", they didnt say `float("4/5")` works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [fractions library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) you can do the following:

```
import fractions

myinput = input("Enter number. ")
try:
    if not myinput.isnumeric():
        myinput = fractions.Fraction(myinput)
except ValueError:
    throw ValueError(myinput + " is not a number")

doubleofmyinput=float(myinput)*2
print(doubleofmyinput)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to input the value as a fraction and NOT show it as a fraction then I would suggest using eval.

```
myinput=float(eval(input("Enter number. ")))
doubleofmyinput= myinput *2  
print(doubleofmyinput)
```

Answer (score 1):

How generous do you want to be in accepting input?

If it's just vulgar fractions (or mixed fractions), you can have a special case for that, either using `.split('/')` or regular expressions to break the input string up into its component parts, convert each separately, then put them together into a `float`, a [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) or a [`Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) (depending on what sort of rounding behaviour you need or can tolerate).

If you want to more generally accept arbitrary expressions, probably best to look for a library to do that; a quick google suggests [simpleeval](https://pypi.org/project/simpleeval/), but there are probably others.

Comment: Accepting vulgar/mixed fractions using Unicode is left as an exercise for the reader :-)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert you input value to the appropriate data type than you can use **eval**  for this :

```
sigma = eval(input("Enter the value of sigma: "))
print(sigma)
```

Thanks :)